# Stacks: Balanced Brackets in C++ Failing

Tags: c++

I am trying to create balancing brackets code in C++. I have two functions, `is_balanced` and `convert_bracket`. Basically, in `is_balanced`, I add left brackets to the stack, and pop them off when the corresponding right bracket appears in the string. However, for some reason `s == convert_bracket(bracketStack.top())` always fails even if `s = '('` and `bracketStack.top() == ')'` (convert_bracket would convert that to a `'('`). I need this condition to pass so that the item can be taken off the stack. Can I get any advice?

```
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

char convert_bracket(char s) {
    switch(s){
        case ')': s = '(';
            break;
        case ']': s= '[';
            break;
        case '}': s= '{';
            break;
    }
    return s;
}

bool is_balanced(string expression) {
    stack<char> bracketStack;
    for(char s : expression){
        if(s == '(' || s == '[' || s == '{'){
            bracketStack.push(s);
        } else {
            if(bracketStack.size()>0 && s == convert_bracket(bracketStack.top())) {
                bracketStack.pop();
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
  if(bracketStack.size() == 0)
  {
        return true;
  }  else {
       return false;
  }
}

int main(){
    string expression = "{[()]}";
    bool answer = is_balanced(expression);
    if(answer)
        cout << "YES\n";
    else cout << "NO\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You push on the 3 open bracket types to the stack. However your case statement is checking for the 3 close types, so it always returns what was passed in so the check will fail.

Switch the logic so its like this :

```
char convert_bracket(char s)
{
     switch(s)
     {
         case '(': s = ')';
                   break;
         case '[': s= ']';
                   break;
         case '{': s= '}';
                   break;
     }
     return s;
}
```

Comment: I also needed these to check for stack size: if(bracketStack.size()>0 && s == convert_bracket(bracketStack.top())) and     if(bracketStack.size() == 0)
    {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

Answer (score 1):

You're referring to the Hackerrank challenge right? The trick is to check if the stack is empty at the end of the process. 
You could have balanced brackets and incomplete brackets in the end!